# pandas Concatenate strings based on column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Names': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
        'Value': ['A1','A2','A3','B1','B2','C1','C2','C3']})

#  Names Value
#0     A    A1
#1     A    A2
#2     A    A3
#3     B    B1
#4     B    B2
#5     C    C1
#6     C    C2
#7     C    C3
```

I wish to get it into the current state:

```
#  Names Values
#0     A    [A1, A2, A3]
#1     B    [B1, B2]
#2     C    [C1, C2, C3]
```

Are there any inbuilt functions in the `pandas` or `numpy` packages that can simplify this? Or am I forced to iterate it through using default python?

Comment: Yup thought about groupby but using `apply` is not really what I was looking for. I suppose its close.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
df.groupby('Names')['Value'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Values')
```

Comment: I was thinking about `groupby` and `apply` too, but I didn't want to do the cop-out answer of `apply`. I think the link provided by other user gave me the answer in `df.groupby('Names').agg(lambda x: list(x))`

Comment: @ycx Actually, you could skip the `lambda`. `df.groupby('Names')['Value'].agg(list)` is all you need.

Comment: Ah thats nice, you have a way to shorten `lambda x: ', '.join(list(x))`?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple:

```
df.groupby('Names')['Value'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Values')
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was thinking about `groupby` and `apply` too, but I didn't want to do the cop-out answer of `apply`. I think your link provided the answer in `df.groupby('Names').agg(lambda x: list(x))`